# How to find the number of events occurring in a Poisson Process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-function, poisson-distribution

I am trying to understand the relationship between the number of events in a Poisson process, and the waiting times between successive events / inter-arrival times.

Suppose I have a Poisson Process $N(t)$ and also suppose the waiting times between successive events are *i.i.d.* exponential $(1)$

Here, how can I find the number of events that occurred before a certain time, say $t = 10$ ?

I understand that with this *Poisson Process*, $N(t)$ ~ Poisson $(t)$, since I assumed that $\lambda$ = $1$ here.

But how to find the number of events before time 10?

Any help is most appreciated.  Thank you so much.

Comment: As we know: the Poisson process $N_t$ *counts* (in other words, ***is***) the number of events before time $t\,.$

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, so we need to find $N(10)$ here.  But $N(t)$, for any fixed $t$, is a random variable.  So, here, we can only find the probability that $N(10)$ = $i$ for some $i$.  Is this correct?  Or, given that the waiting times are iid exponential (1), is it possible to actually find what N(10) is?  Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: You can only find the probability that $N(10)=i\,.$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!